# Delphi check if TThread is still running

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am using TThread, i just need to find out if thread is still running and terminate the application if it takes to long.

Ex:

```
MyThread := TMyThread.Create;
MyThread .Resume;
MyThread.Terminate;

total := 0;
while MyThread.isRunning = true do // < i need something like this
begin
  // show message to user to wait a little longer we are still doing stuff
  sleep(1000);
  total := total + 1000;
  if total > 60000 then 
     exit;
  end;
```

Is this possible with Delphi?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The straight answer to your question is the [`Finished`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Finished) property of `TThread`. However, I don't recommend that. It leads you to that rather nasty `Sleep` based loop that you present in the question.

There are a number of cleaner options, including at least the following:

1. Use [`WaitFor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.WaitFor) to block until the thread completes. This will block the calling thread which will preclude showing UI, or responding to the user.
2. Use [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242.aspx) in a loop, passing the thread handle. This allows you to wait until the thread completes, but also service the UI.
3. Implement an event handler for the [`OnTerminate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.OnTerminate) event. This allows you to be notified in an event driven manner of the thread's demise.

I recommend that you use one of these options instead of your home-grown `Sleep` based loop. In my experience, option 3 generally leads to the cleanest code. But it is hard to give rigid advice without knowing all the requirements. Only you have that knowledge.

Comment: No isRunning, so sad. WaitFor block so that defeats the purpose of threads. I´m avoiding MsgWaitForMultipleObjects  since it is easy to cause unexpect problems in COM applications. So i guess i am stuck with OnTerminate with is far from good since will have to add a lot of code just to check if all threads are finished.

Comment: See my update. There is `TThread.Finished`. I urge you not to do it, but it does exist.

Comment: I dont have TThread.Finished and just found out that OnTerminate is useless. Docs at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TThread.OnTerminate say OnTerminate is called after Execute and before destroy, that is not true OnTerminate is called when you try to free the thread but the Thread.Free calls WaitFor blocking your main thread. This behavior prevents the use of  OnTerminate to set a flag to indicate the termination of the thread since it will block until precessing is done anyway.

Comment: Why are you calling `Free`? I thought you wanted to wait until it was finished. `Finished` is easy to implement for yourself. Add a boolean to your thread class and set it true when Execute exits. Or similar.

Comment: @uacaman: the documentation is not wrong. `OnTerminate` **IS** called immediately after `Execute()` exits, before the thread is destroyed. Look at the source code for `TThread` in `Classes.pas` for yourself. `OnTerminate` is called via `TThread.Synchronize()`, and `TThread.WaitFor()` runs a loop that allows pending `Synchronize()` requests to continue being processed while `Waitfor()` is waiting for the thread to terminate. Sounds like you are simply not managing your `TThread` object correctly to begin with.

Comment: I cannot understand that comment. Sorry.

Comment: Making it simple, when you use onTerminate on the main thread it is busy with doing your stuff. onterminate will fire only when you release control back to the OS. That makes it impossible to use onTerminate on the main thread.

Comment: Call `CheckSynchronize` periodically from the main thread. Typically this will be invoked in a console app from the function you supply to `WakeMainThread`. I take it this is a console app or a service since you presumably are not blocking the main thread of a GUI app.